# DispatcherServlet classnot found and org.apache.jasper.JasperException

Tags: java, mysql, spring, maven

I have provided almost all dependency which are necessary for simple spring web application
 but while running the project getting 
 ""java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet "" error

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.dnp</groupId>
<artifactId>DronasMMVC</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>DronasMMVC Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>4.3.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <servlet.version>3.0.1</servlet.version>
    <mysql.connector.version>5.1.9</mysql.connector.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--Servlet-Api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Servlet API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- MySQL database driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>DronasMMVC</finalName>
</build>
```

This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
            <el-ignored>true</el-ignored>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>view/login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Can your dependencies be resolved?

Comment: @Càphêđen   Yes dependencies are resolved.

Comment: Post your web.xml not only the header.

Comment: Maybe the new dependant jars are not deployed. Please check steps here http://www.dineshonjava.com/2016/03/solving-java-lang-ClassNotFoundException-org-springframework-web-servlet-DispatcherServlet.html?m=1

Comment: @M.Deinum posted complete web.xml file

Comment: In your pom the `javax.servlet` dependency is duplicated and should have `<scope>provided</scope>`. Do a `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` to remove all dependencies and force a refresh on them (could be a borked jar in your list). If that doesn't resolve the issue I'm wondering how you are deploying things to the server.

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you for help but your both suggestions dosen't worked for me.
This is my first project in spring very exited to develop web app in spring but stucked because of this error.

Comment: Then how are you deploying your application? Are you creating a war and deploy it or use the IDE?

Comment: I have checked  spring-webmvc-4.2.0.jar file and it contains DispatcherServlet.Class file. Still  m getting this error!!

Comment: @M.Deinum I am Using Eclipse IDE (neon 3)

Comment: Create a war and deploy it. Looks like something is wrong with your maven integration in Eclipse, feels like it doesn't export the proper libraries when you deploy it from within eclipse (or however you are executing things).